# how to ignore spring security CSRF for specific URL's in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, rest-client

how can I ignore CSRF security for specific URL which is like "/workflow/**".
Except for this URL, I need both authorization and CSRF security for all the URL's and methods.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private PranaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AllExceptUrlStartedWith("/workflow"))          
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**", "/tasklist").authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")        
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and().formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .and().formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)         
        .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    private static class AllExceptUrlStartedWith implements RequestMatcher {

        private static final String[] ALLOWED_METHODS =
                new String[] {"GET"};

        private final String[] allowedUrls;

        public AllExceptUrlStartedWith(String... allowedUrls) {
            this.allowedUrls = allowedUrls;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String method = request.getMethod();
            for(String allowedMethod : ALLOWED_METHODS) {
                if (allowedMethod.equals(method)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            for (String allowedUrl : allowedUrls) {
                if (uri.startsWith(allowedUrl)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/styles/**").antMatchers("/scripts/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

how can I ignore CSRF security for specific URL which is like "/workflow/**".
Except for this URL, I need both authorization and CSRF security for all the URL's and methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my project I'm using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        ...
        .csrf()
            // Allow unsecured requests to H2 console
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AllExceptUrlsStartedWith("/console"))
        ...
}

private static class AllExceptUrlsStartedWith implements RequestMatcher {

        private static final String[] ALLOWED_METHODS =
            new String[] {"GET", "HEAD", "TRACE", "OPTIONS"};

        private final String[] allowedUrls;

        public AllExceptUrlsStartedWith(String... allowedUrls) {
            this.allowedUrls = allowedUrls;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // replicate default behavior (see CsrfFilter.DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher class)
            String method = request.getMethod();
            for (String allowedMethod : ALLOWED_METHODS) {
                if (allowedMethod.equals(method)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // apply our own exceptions
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            for (String allowedUrl : allowedUrls) {
                if (uri.startsWith(allowedUrl)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

In this example I've disabled CSRF protection for `/console`.

---

Update: [since Spring Security 4.0 you can simplify it to a single line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/179#issuecomment-114999129):

```
csrf()
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/nocsrf","/ignore/startswith/**")
```

Comment: Hi @Slava: its not working for me!! I am getting 403 forbidden error both for /login and for /workflow/**...... any help??

Comment: So, please, post your updated spring security configuration somewhere (pastebin, for instance).

Comment: Thanks Slava. Actually It was my mistake, was getting error because of my company specific dependencies.
It is working, now I have CSRF disabled for "/workflow" calls and enabled for all other rest calls
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Using `antPathMatcher.match()` will make the minimal code for defining wildcard URLs like `/console/**`. Which you can refer in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only one purpose of answering in this thread is to explain and use `antPathMatcher` whose advantages can be taken to protect many urls with ant matchers.

From Doc

> **`.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(RequestMatcher requireCsrfProtectionMatcher)`**
>
> ---
>
> Specify the RequestMatcher to use for determining when CSRF should be applied. The default is to ignore GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS and process all other requests.

Note that by default `GET`, `HEAD`, `TRACE`, `OPTIONS` requests are ignored. If you want to override this defaults configure `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(implementation_of_RequestMatcher)`.

In implementation of RequestMatcher define all the URL's which needs to be protected. **You are done**

**Say you want URL's `/api/**` to be ensured for CSRF protection**.

```java
@Autowired
RequestMatcher csrfProtectedMatchers;

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/app/user/*")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfProtectedMatchers);
}

@Bean
public RequestMatcher getCsrfProtectedMatchers()
{
    UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    List<String> protectedUrlPatterns = Arrays.asList("/api/**", "/logout");

    return new RequestMatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            String uri = urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(request);
            for (String pattern : protectedUrlPatterns)
            {
                if (antPathMatcher.match(pattern, uri))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

**Logic explained**
suppose URL: `http://localhost:8080/csrf/api/test1`
`String uri = urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(request);`
uri => `/api/test1`;
`antPathMatcher.match("/api/**", "/api/test1")` => `true`

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 6, [`CsrfConfigurer#ignoringRequestMatchers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.2.1/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html#ignoringRequestMatchers(java.lang.String...)) can be used.

For example:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/workflow/**"));
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answer for my own question... thanks to @Slava

```
@Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

        @Autowired
        private PranaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AllExceptUrlStartedWith("/workflow"))          
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**", "/tasklist").authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")        
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and().formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)         
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private static class AllExceptUrlStartedWith implements RequestMatcher {

            private static final String[] ALLOWED_METHODS =
                    new String[] {"GET"};

            private final String[] allowedUrls;

            public AllExceptUrlStartedWith(String... allowedUrls) {
                this.allowedUrls = allowedUrls;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                String method = request.getMethod();
                for(String allowedMethod : ALLOWED_METHODS) {
                    if (allowedMethod.equals(method)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                String uri = request.getRequestURI();
                for (String allowedUrl : allowedUrls) {
                    if (uri.startsWith(allowedUrl)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/styles/**").antMatchers("/scripts/**");
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }
    }
```